# Average age from birth date in django

Tags: django, django-aggregation

In my django(3.0.5) application I am trying to get average age from date of birth in a model. I am using MySql database.
Here is how I tried:

Model:

```
class ShippingStaff(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField('Full Name', max_length=200)
    birth_date = models.DateField('Date of Birth', null=True, blank=True)
```

Customer Filter:

```
@register.filter(name='age')
def age(bday, d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = datetime.date.today()
    return (d.year - bday.year) - int((d.month, d.day) < (bday.month, bday.day))
```

Views:

```
def home(request):
shipping_staff = ShippingStaff.objects.aggregate(staff_count=Count('full_name'),
                                                 avg_age=Avg(custom_time.age('birth_date'))
```

I get error like:

```
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'year'
Exception Location: /home/smrashel/jahaji/crewdatabd/templatetags/custom_time.py in age, line 31
which is

return (d.year - bday.year) - int((d.month, d.day) < (bday.month, bday.day))
```

How can I solve this?
Any  help will be much appreciated.

Comment: apparently you're accessing a string when trying to access the `.year` property.

Comment: @monkut how can I make it an integer?

Comment: Do you have rows with empty dates in your DB? Maybe you should also check bday is not empty before accessing its fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change str to date. So you could use `datetime.strptime` like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '08/12/12'

d = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%m/%d/%y')


print(d.year)
>>> 2012
```

In your case:

```
@register.filter(name='age')
def age(bday, d=None):
    b = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%m/%d/%y')
    if d is None:
        d = datetime.date.today()
    return (d.year - bday.year) - int((d.month, d.day) < (bday.month, bday.day))
```

Of course it depends how your str date looks like, you need to adapt it to your needs

Comment: In MySql database my birth_date is like '1985-01-15'. I tried  bday = datetime.strptime(bday, '%Y-%m-%d'). Now I get:  time data 'birth_date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'.

Comment: then use ```d = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d')```

Comment: Here is my updated filter:

@register.filter(name='age')
def age(bday, d=None):
    bday = datetime.strptime(bday, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if d is None:
        d = datetime.date.today()
    return (d.year - bday.year) - int((d.month, d.day) < (bday.month, bday.day))

I still get the error: 
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
time data 'birth_date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: ```strptime``` have to receive date in format '1985-01-15' where 1985 is year, 01 month and 15 day. If you pass date in other format this Exception is raised. Also if month will be out of range like '1985-14-14' this same Exception will appear. Make sure that everywhere you have date in the same format.